# Google reCAPTCHA with Spring WebFlow

Tags: java, jsp, recaptcha, spring-webflow

By adding data-callback parameter into my submit button tag is seemingly overriden triggering of the event of the transition to the next screen of our form.

The submit button is implemented via input

```
<input type="submit" name="namespaced event id" ... />
```

namespaced id looks like this:

```
namespace_eventId_event
```

Does anyone know how I can trigger the spring webflow transition through the jquery data-callback function?

Adding action with eventId and submiting the form does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this exact type of issue is to create hidden field using javascript (jQuery in my case) where the flow id is stored.

Then it is possible to submit form calling the submit function on form selector.